# How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, escaping

How do I insert a record in a column having varchar data type having single quote in it?

**Example**: first name is `ROBERT` and last name is **`D'COSTA`**

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Use two single-quotes

```
SQL> SELECT 'D''COSTA' name FROM DUAL;

NAME
-------
D'COSTA
```

Alternatively, use the [new (10g+) quoting method](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00218):

```
SQL> SELECT q'$D'COSTA$' NAME FROM DUAL;

NAME
-------
D'COSTA
```

Comment: What if we need two successive single quotes? Is this case the "alternative" method is meant for?

Comment: @RichouHunter You would use four single quotes : `'D''''COSTA' => D''COSTA`. Alternatively: `q'$D''COSTA$'`

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! For reference, here's another [Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) regarding the alternate quoting syntax for text literals that reads a little better than the linked PL/SQL doc.

Comment: @Dank I agree, the SQL reference is clearer than the PL/SQL doc on this subject (I've updated the link to the most recent version).

Answer (score 2):

I found the above answer giving an error with Oracle SQL, you also must use square brackets, below;

`SQL> SELECT Q'[Paddy O'Reilly]' FROM DUAL;`

---

Result: **Paddy O'Reilly**