# Single quote in dbms_output statement?

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I need to include single quotes in dbms_output statement. I've tried this:

```
 dbms_output.put_line('\''first_name||'\'');
```

Here first_name is **`variable`**; I need to display this inside single quotes.

Comment: if first_name holds xyx then my output would be 'xyz'.this is wat i tried to get.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you'd escape by doubling up:

```
 dbms_output.put_line('''' || first_name || '''');
```

or using the [q-quote](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=311) mechanism:

```
 dbms_output.put_line(q'[']'||first_name||q'[']');
```

eg:

```
SQL> var b1 varchar2(30)
SQL> exec :b1 := 'this is a test';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec  dbms_output.put_line(q'[']'||:b1||q'[']');
'this is a test'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec  dbms_output.put_line(''''||:b1||'''');
'this is a test'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec  dbms_output.put_line(chr(39)||:b1||chr(39));
'this is a test'

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: beat me to it by 2 seconds :)

Comment: ya dude I've got output by using first one but i seems to be tedious unstructured too!dose second one works!?

Comment: @ThiyaguATR q-quotes may be a bit verbose for very short strings like this, but it is worth being familiar with them for use in longer text such as a dynamic SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is only for PL/SQL and must be active.

```
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DELETE FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYFIELD <> ''A'';');
end;
/
```

Assuming you want to match a `CHAR` 'A'.