# Shell script single quotes issue

Tags: shell, plsql, ksh

Below is my shell script snippet. I want serviceVer output should be with quotes. Like '7.6.%'

Currently, it is coming as Output: 7.6.%

Expected =>  Output: '7.6.%'

```
    #!/bin/ksh
    serviceVer VARCHAR2(200) := '7.6.%';
    BEGIN

 DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output: '|| serviceVer );
.......
```

Please help.

I tried with `serviceVer VARCHAR2(200) := '\'7.6.%\'';`

But looks like it is not correct...

Comment: bash is not ksh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working example:

```
DECLARE
serviceVer VARCHAR2(200) := '7.6.%';
BEGIN
dbms_output.put_line('Output: '|| ''''||serviceVer||'''') ;
END ;
```

Tested on https://livesql.oracle.com/

Answer (score 0):

The restriction comes from your database, not bash.

Maybe use:

```
serviceVer VARCHAR2(200) := ''''7.6.%'''';
```

Or better:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output: ' || '''' || serviceVer || '''');
```

You can check:

[Single quote in dbms_output statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690022/single-quote-in-dbms-output-statement)

Comment: Using Oracle. It needs single quotes

Comment: It is for oracle, yes. Did you tested or checked the other link ? Here is a list or syntax for what you need: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html  Try like this DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Output: ' || '''' || serviceVer || '''');