# oracle regular expression extracting string inside tags

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

This is for my practice, I've a text like:

```
 "lovely heart"<abc.def@hotmail.com>,
 "<<*>>Freeeky<<*>> Jack" <aabbcc@gmail.com>,
 "heavens's kingk*ng '-'asdf" <bbb@yahoo.co.in>
 "sample[^-^]"<sample@ss.com>
```

I need to extract only:

```
abc.def@hotmail.com
aabbcc@gmail.com
bbb@yahoo.co.in
sample@ss.com
```

Here's my try, but still its half or less done.

```
WITH t AS
     (SELECT '"lovely heart"<abc.def@hotmail.com>,
"<<*>>Freeeky<<*>> Jack" <aabbcc@gmail.com>, 
"heavens''s kingk*ng ''-''asdf" <bbb@yahoo.com>' word
     FROM dual
     )
SELECT regexp_substr(word, '<(.*@.*)>',1,LEVEL, NULL,1)
FROM t
     CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(word, '<(.*@.*)>');
```

some results are like:

```
<*>>Freeeky<<*>> Jack" <aabbcc@gmail.com
```

Any good solution please.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by half done? Didn't this give you expected result?

Comment: @RohitJain, updated with unexpected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your regex is, the first `.*` after `<` will match all characters before the `@`, as a `dot(.)` in regex can match any character except the newline. So, it would even match `<` and `>`. Here's how it matches your string:

```
'"< <<*>>Freeeky<<*>> Jack" <aabbcc@gmail.com  >"'
  ^ ^                                       ^  ^
  | -----------------------------------------  |
  |                      |                     |
 Match the first `<`   (.*@.*)           Match the last `>`.
```

So, the captured group is:

```
<<*>>Freeeky<<*>> Jack" <aabbcc@gmail.com
```

Which is that you got. You can change `.*` to `[^<>]*` to match any characters except `<` and `>`:

Use the following regex:

```
'<([^<>]*@[^<>]*)>'
```

Comment: And one more question, I've manually added the extra quotes for the single quotes for the text, Is there other way to use only in one query?

Comment: @ajmalmhd04. I am afraid, I can't answer that. Have no experience in Oracle DB. Sorry for that.

Comment: Okay, no problem, Let me swim deep in to regexp and wait for others answers.

Comment: @ajmalmhd04. I guess that is the correct way to escape single quotes. [See this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2875295/1679863)

Comment: Yeah, agree, but how would I know if I'm only having the text and use the query directly for a large data?!

Comment: @ajmalmhd04. You can also use literal quoting - `q'[heavens's kingk*ng]'`. Look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315340/pl-sql-how-to-escape-single-quote-in-a-string). I guess this would be easier.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34685/discussion-between-ajmalmhd04-and-rohit-jain)

Comment: @ajmalmhd04. Sorry I can't chat now. I'm in my office.