# How to insert a value with embedded single quotes in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

How to insert the following ENTIRE string to a varchar2(31) field.

```
u1salcd||' '||dmname
```

I get the following error message.

```
INSERT INTO EXPORTS_DEFS ( EXPORT_ID, EXPORT_ID2  ) VALUES ('ucsalcd||' '||dmname','L');
Error at Command Line:1 Column:71
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try:

```
INSERT INTO EXPORTS_DEFS ( EXPORT_ID, EXPORT_ID2  ) 
VALUES ('ucsalcd||'' ''||dmname','L');
```

Comment: yay! it worked, can u pls explain how it works and wht i need to do for other special characters?

Comment: Single quote is escape character in oracle, so if you need to insert one single quote, in insert query two should be there.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the `||` symbol. You need to escape the embedded single quotes. This is done by using two single quotes:

```
INSERT INTO EXPORTS_DEFS 
 (EXPORT_ID, EXPORT_ID2  ) 
VALUES 
 ('u1salcd||'' ''||dmname','L');
```

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/15c7f/1

Comment: it worked, can u pls explain how it works and wht i need to do for other special characters?

Comment: As I said: to "escape" a single quote, simply write two single quotes. That's the only special character that needs this kind of escaping. For more details please read the manual http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements003.htm#i42617  (Btw: what does *can u pls* mean? I have never seen a "u pls" thing. What is it?)