# Escaping single quote in stored oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, store

I have a stored procedure which reads value from the table and then using update query it appends a prefix in it and update the table.

But the issue that I am getting the value in table contains single quote(') so when I use it in update query is not working.

How can I escape this single quote by two single quotes?
Briefly I want to check...:
 1. if single quote exists in the value fetched from table.
 2. if yes, then replace single quote with double quote else do nothing
How can this be achievd?

Comment: If you're selecting the value into a variable and then using that in the update then it doesn't matter if it contains a single quote, that will be handled and preserved automatically. You might need to show your code so we can see what you're actually doing. And the error you're getting, of course.

Answer (score 2):

To escape a single ' you use another '. For example a string containing a single ' looks like this:

```
''''
```

Two ' as start and finish of the string and a ' to escape the ' you actually want.

Similar question:
[How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: yes, but before that i should have a method which value has single quote and which not. As the data is coming from table I don't know where single quote is used

Comment: Please post an example because usually you don't have this problem.