# sql plus oracle ASCII() how to know ascii code of single quote

Tags: sql

how to know ASCII code of single quote in sql oracle using ASCII()
i tried select ASCII(''') from dual;
but it showing an error
which escape character can be used for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to handle a single quote in Oracle SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: Also, the ASCII code for a single quote is 39. You can just look it up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use two single quotes to escape it:

```
select ASCII('''') from dual;
```

Looks a little weird but that should do it.

Comment: @user3135829, No problem but I'd rather get "thanks" in the form of you accepting my answer :) see the [faq] for details.