# having issues with single quotes using like 'string token' in execute immediate statement

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Here is the section of code, I am using ' ' blah ' ' to escape single quotes but I guess its not working:

```
declare
my_func varchar2(20) :='test_func';

begin 
execute immediate 'insert into TABLE_TEST (OUTPUT) select ' || my_func || ' from dual where TABLE_TEST.FUNCTION_NAME like ' 'VALIDATION1_%' '  ';
end;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VALIDATION1_%" when expecting one of the following:

   & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem return
   returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or
   like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk member
   submultiset
The symbol "* was inserted before "VALIDATION1_%" to continue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to [escape the single quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql) with another single quote (which is good), but there is an extra space in between the two. That has to go.

Change

```
' from dual where TABLE_TEST.FUNCTION_NAME like ' 'VALIDATION1_%' '  '
```

to

```
' from dual where TABLE_TEST.FUNCTION_NAME like ''VALIDATION1_%''  '
```

Comment: Doing that gives me an ORA-00904 invalid identifier error for TABLE_TEST.FUNCTION_NAME

Comment: Well, does TABLE_TEST have a column FUNCTION_NAME ?

Comment: Yes it does have the column FUNCTION_NAME

Comment: I guess I figured it out, nothing to do with your solution which does solve my original problem. I needed to add table_test next to dual so it should have read ' from dual, table_test where .........'

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this it's much simpler to use the new `q` syntax for literal strings, e.g.:

```
execute immediate 'insert into TABLE_TEST (OUTPUT) select ' || my_func ||
  q[' from dual where TABLE_TEST.FUNCTION_NAME like 'VALIDATION1_%' ]';
```