# ORA-01756:quoted string not properly terminated Exception

Tags: c#, oracle

Am doing an insert statement using the below query but throws the exception on the title. I have tried to debug the query but cant figure out where am getting it wrong. I do not want to use a parameterised query.

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO AML_PERCENTAGE_COMPARATOR ( FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, WHOLENAME, PERCENTAGE ) VALUES ('" + ListOfAML[i].firstName + "','" + ListOfAML[i].middleName + "','" + ListOfAML[i].lastName + "','" + ListOfAML[i].wholeName + "','" + compare + "')");
```

Comment: do you think you should use preparedstatement instead ?

Comment: Are all column types character? What are the value of your strings? Maybe one of them includes `'` like `O'Conner`? You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: @SonerGönül yes, it contains  (al-Mu'ayyad)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nvoigt [already explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29209934/447156) your problem. I try show it as an example;

As I said, single quotes have a special meaning in SQL DBMS. If you wanna use them in your command as a [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal), [you need to double them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/how-to-handle-a-single-quote-in-oracle-sql).

Best way to handle them using [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Also this kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(var con = OracleConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AML_PERCENTAGE_COMPARATOR(FIRSTNAME, MIDDLENAME, LASTNAME, WHOLENAME, PERCENTAGE )
                      VALUES(:firstname, :middlename, :lastname, :wholeName, :compare)";
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firstname", ListOfAML[i].firstName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("middlename", ListOfAML[i].middleName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("lastname", ListOfAML[i].lastName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("wholeName", ListOfAML[i].wholeName);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("compare", compare);

   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: when i implement above i get  `ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number`

Comment: @Lawrence Ops, sorry, that was my fault. I mixed `OracleCommand` with `OleDbCommand`. In `OracleCommand`, you need to use `:` prefix in front of your parameter names in your command. Updated my answer based on that. You can read [Using Parameters](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html) article as well.

Answer (score 3):

> I do not want to use a parameterised query.

Well, there's your problem.

You can insert Athos, Aramis and Portos. But then, D’Artagnan comes along and your statement breaks.

Use parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

If ' is the problem then replacing it with '' may help eg

```
"D'Artagnan".Replace( "'", "''")
```