# How to extract a sub-string from a string?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
fnd YGY LOOKUP_TYPE = 'welcome' HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = 'home' hello how are you?
```

Above is the string and i want output as

```
welcome
home
```

Comment: Are you wanting to get any text that is enclosed in single quote marks ? Or is the text and the string exactly what you need to search ?

Comment: Please post some more sample data and desired result to clarify your need. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: basically i want to find values of lookup_type.

Comment: So you are looking for strings like `LOOKUP_TYPE = '...'`; is that part fixed? that is, can you have things like `LOOKUP_TYPE='...'` or `LOOKUP_TYPE      =            '...'` with more tha one space around the equal sign?

Comment: the part which is fixed is this
LOOKUP_TYPE = '...'

Comment: Should the result hold a value per record or can the values be presented as a delimited string?

Answer (score 3):

**Query 1**:

*Note: single quotes need to be escaped in a text literal*:

```
WITH test_data ( string ) AS (
  SELECT 'LOOKUP_TYPE = ''welcome'' LOOKUP_TYPE = ''home'''
  FROM DUAL
)
SELECT SUBSTR( string, quote1 + 1, quote2 - quote1 - 1 ) AS first_quoted_string,
       SUBSTR( string, quote3 + 1, quote4 - quote3 - 1 ) AS second_quoted_string,
FROM   (
  SELECT string,
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 1 ) AS quote1,
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 2 ) AS quote2,
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 3 ) AS quote3,
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 4 ) AS quote4
  FROM   test_data
)
```

**Output**:

```
FIRST_QUOTED_STRING SECOND_QUOTED_STRING
------------------- --------------------
welcome             home
```

**Query 2**:

*Note: Alternative [text literal](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617) quote demiliters `q'[your string]'` used so that single quotation marks do not need to be escaped*:

```
WITH test_data ( string ) AS (
  SELECT q'[LOOKUP_TYPE = 'welcome' LOOKUP_TYPE = 'home']'
  FROM DUAL
),
quotes ( string, quote_start, quote_end, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT string,
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 1 ),
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 2 ),
         1
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  INSTR( string, '''', 1, 2 ) > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT string,
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 2 * lvl + 1 ),
         INSTR( string, '''', 1, 2 * lvl + 2 ),
         lvl + 1
  FROM   quotes
  WHERE  INSTR( string, '''', 1, 2 * lvl + 2 ) > 0
)
SELECT SUBSTR( string, quote_start + 1, quote_end - quote_start - 1 ) AS quoted_string
FROM   quotes
```

**Output**:

```
QUOTED_STRING
-------------
welcome
home
```

**Query 3 - Regular Expressions**:

*Note: `:your_string` bind variable used to get input (you could also use a text literal instead)*:

```
WITH test_data ( string ) AS (
  SELECT :your_string FROM DUAL
),
quotes ( string, quoted_string, lvl, max_lvl ) AS (
  SELECT string,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, q'[LOOKUP_TYPE\s*=\s*("|''?)(.*?)\1]', 1, 1, NULL, 2 ),
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT( string, q'[LOOKUP_TYPE\s*=\s*("|''?)(.*?)\1]' )
  FROM   test_data
  WHERE  REGEXP_COUNT( string, q'[LOOKUP_TYPE\s*=\s*("|''?)(.*?)\1]' ) > 0
UNION ALL
  SELECT string,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR( string, q'[LOOKUP_TYPE\s*=\s*("|''?)(.*?)\1]', 1, lvl + 1, NULL, 2 ),
         lvl + 1,
         max_lvl
  FROM   quotes
  WHERE  lvl < max_lvl
)
SELECT quoted_string
FROM   quotes
```

**Output**:

```
QUOTED_STRING
-------------
welcome
home
```

Comment: why did u change the string?
please keep the string same as i posted and in my string there is not double quotes only single quotes are there

Comment: @HimanshAgarwal If you want [a single quote `'` in a string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2875257/1509264) it needs to be escaped using a second single quote `''` - the string would only have a single quote each location on output. The text of the string is irrelevant to the effectiveness of the answer - if you want it with your text then just substitute that in (escaping the single quotes).

Comment: dude this is my string
FDGF YGY LOOKUP_TYPE = 'welcome' HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = 'home' hello how are you?

i cannot change anything in my string.

Comment: @HimanshAgarwal and this answer will find the values in the quotes regardless of what the value of the string is.... put your string in and you will get the same answers.

Comment: This was the string that you used 
LOOKUP_TYPE = ''welcome'' LOOKUP_TYPE = ''home''

this is the string that i am using 
FDGF YGY LOOKUP_TYPE = 'welcome' HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = 'home' hello how are you?

and this is the error which i am getting 
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 42

Comment: @HimanshAgarwal [Escape your single quotes with a second single quote](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2875257/1509264) or pass the string in as a bind parameter.

Comment: @MT0 - maybe you could use the alternative string delimiters of q'[here's my string]'. That way Himansh will be reassured even though yours is exactly the same in function.

Comment: @HimanshAgarwal - can I suggest that you look at the basics of quoting string literals in Oracle. Particularly with regard to strings containing quotes. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm

Comment: @BriteSponge updated with the `q'[text literal]'` syntax and a bind variable example.

Comment: Query 3 - Regular Expressions:
is working now what i want that this solution should also work with this

DSFSFSDFSDFSD LOOKUP_TYPE = "XXX_ASD" ASAD HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = "XX_DSASD"

Comment: can you merge both the query?

Comment: @HimanshAgarwal What do you mean by merging both queries? The 3rd option will handle both single and double quotes if that is what you are asking?

Comment: Query 3 - Regular Expressions: is working now what i want that this solution should also work with this DSFSFSDFSDFSD LOOKUP_TYPE = "XXX_ASD" ASAD HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = ''XX_DSAS''

Comment: @HimanshAgarwal The 3rd option will handle both single and double quotes if that is what you are asking?

Comment: i have a string where there is  
some times single quotes 'welcome' and some times double quotes "welcome" and some time two single quotes like this ' 'welcome' '

Comment: @MT0 did you get what am i asking?

Comment: @MT0 dude it is still searching only for 'welcome' and "welcome" but skipping ' 'welcome' '

Comment: @MT0 did u get what am i asking?

Answer (score 1):

```
with    t (col) as (select q'[fnd YGY LOOKUP_TYPE = 'welcome' HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = "home" hello LOOKUP_TYPE = ''man'' how are you?]' from dual)

select  rtrim(regexp_replace(col,q'[(.*?LOOKUP_TYPE\s*=\s*(''|'|")(.*?)\2|.+)]','\3,'),',') as lookup_types
from    t
```

---

```
+------------------+
|   LOOKUP_TYPES   |
+------------------+
| welcome,home,man |
+------------------+
```

Comment: Query 3 - Regular Expressions: is working now what i want that this solution should also work with this DSFSFSDFSDFSD LOOKUP_TYPE = "XXX_ASD" ASAD HELO HIASDH LOOKUP_TYPE = ''XX_DSAS''

Comment: I think you wanted to comment another answer

Comment: can you do what i want?

Comment: first thing is i am getting string from querying something but here string is fixed
second i am having the string where there is two single quotes like this 
''welcome''
single double quote 
"welcome"
and single single quote
'welcome'

Comment: This solution returns all values as a delimited string if you need the values in separated rows you have the solution given by @MTO

Comment: your query is providing solution for the string where there is single quote like this
'welcome'
but i have the string where there is 
one time single quote 'welcome'
two time single quote ''welcome''
one time double quote "welcome"

Comment: You want double quotes? Always?

Comment: some times single quotes and some times double quotes and some time two single quotes like this ' 'welcome' '

Comment: O.K. give me a minute

Comment: Wait, there is a cleaner solution

Comment: fantastic 
can you just do one more thing 
here our string is fixed 
i want this as bind variable

Comment: Check out the cleaner solution.

Comment: For bind variable use `select rtrim(regexp_replace(:my_bind_variable... from dual`

Comment: dude your query is working fine but i am getting all the values in single row can you make it appear in separated rows