# how to save value in oracle using nq'[]' operator

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need to save string with single quote in column with `nvarchar2` data type. I find here

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm

that I can save it using quote operator. I try to do it in my SQL query

```
insert into table (question_pattern_id, text, event_selection_id, context_theme_id, placeholder_body) 
values ('65', nq'[]', '', '', nq'[]')
```

but it inserts `??` instead of

Before data was added by query

```
insert into table (question_pattern_id, text, event_selection_id, context_theme_id, placeholder_body) 
values ('65', n'', '', '', n'')
```

and everything was saved correctly

Comment: If `n''` works, then why do you want to use something else?

Comment: n'' works if i don't set value with quotes, but if i use n''"&' then will be error 
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00917: missing comma

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875257/